# Code got deleted after accidental pull from git origin

Tags: git, commit, vscode-extensions, pull, git-extensions

I used the git GUI in VS Code to stage, commit and then push my code to the remote origin. It did not work so I accidentally pulled my previous commit which basically had no code and my entire project was replaced by the previous commit deleting all the added files in the process. I cannot seem to find those files anywhere. How can I restore those files?

Comment: Did you ever commit your previous changes to the repository?

Comment: I did but apparently it is not showing in my commits

Answer (score 1):

If you committed code locally you can restore it using [`git reflog`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-reflog).

In [Git Extensions app](https://github.com/gitextensions/gitextensions) it is as easy as toggling the option:

[image]

...and then checking out the "lost" commit:

[image]

Comment: Thank you I was able to retrieve my deleted code. Apparently my commit was not pushed  because of a detached head. The issue has been fixed.